# Storing a Specific Generated Random number as a Variable (PHP)

Tags: php, random

I'm trying to use random numbers to store the image names of uploaded images which works perfectly. Now, I have to use the number in another function, but it changes when used in another function.

```
$rand = rand() . '.png';  

if(isset($_POST["image"])){
    $data = $_POST["image"];
    $image_array_1 = explode(";", $data);
    $image_array_2 = explode(",", $image_array_1[1]);
    $data = base64_decode($image_array_2[1]);
    file_put_contents( $rand, $data);
    echo '<img src="includes/'.$rand.'" class="img-thumbnail" />';
}
```

This is to display the cropped image and give it a name, before upload. Now to upload:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $pic = $rand; 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (pic) VALUES ('$pic');
}
```

I expect that when using the $rand in the second function, the generated number is the same.

Comment: They've clicked submit and gone to a new page?  That global doesn't exist, maybe you want sessions? https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: Please show us the flow of how these methods are related to each other. How are they called?

Comment: The flow is just the way you see it. There is nothing in-between those two functions.

Answer (score 0):

To start, this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (pic) VALUES ('$pic');
```

Should be this (closing double quote)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (pic) VALUES ('$pic')";
```

This should work for you:

```
$image_name = prepareImage();

if($image_name !== false) {
    $sql = createSql($image_name);
} else {
    $sql = false;
}

function prepareImage() {
    if (isset($_POST["image"])) {
        $rand = rand() . '.png';
        $data = $_POST["image"];
        $image_array_1 = explode(";", $data);
        $image_array_2 = explode(",", $image_array_1[1]);
        $data = base64_decode($image_array_2[1]);
        file_put_contents($rand, $data);
        echo '<img src="includes/' . $rand . '" class="img-thumbnail" />';
        return $rand;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function createSql($image_name) {
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $pic = $image_name;
        return "INSERT INTO users (pic) VALUES ('$pic')";
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

prepareImage is your first function with a false catch if the image wasn't posted and therefore the name couldn't be set. It returns false or the image name.

The second function uses the image name to create your sql line and returns the sql on success or false on failure. I set false as the return so you can check against this later on.

The code at the top first tries to display/get your image name. The next bit checks against this and generates your SQL if possible.

Comment: Zachary, your code's great, only that the insert query isn't working. I also tried lifting your code directly, but it returned a blank page with no error.

Comment: Yeah it's built for internal checking so it doesn't echo anything, replace the first "return false;" with "echo 'image not set';" and the second with "echo 'submit not set';"

Comment: If it's not working it'll be one of those two not getting passed to the server

Comment: It echoes "submit not set"

Comment: This means $_POST["submit"] does not exist, do you have an input with the name/id set to "submit" in your form?

Comment: You could just remove the entire if statement in the section function and leave         $pic = $image_name;
 return "INSERT INTO users (pic) VALUES ('$pic')";